# use onError to change the src of img tag reactjs

Tags: reactjs

```
<img  alt="" className="avi" onError={console.log("error")} src={photoURL} />
```

I have this img tag and if the user has provided an invalid link I want to set the src to a default image.

I have tried to do

```
<img  alt="" className="avi" onError={this.src='defaultimgurl'} src={photoURL} />
```

How can I change the src if the error occurs.

Comment: Don't you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: no @EvgenyTimoshenko

Comment: `onError` should be a function.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to save the initial url into the state and if there is an error change the state with the default url, and use the state as the src of the image

```
state = {
  url: photoUrl
}

callBack(){
  this.setState({
    url: defaultUrl
  })
}

render() {
  const {url} = this.state;
  return (
      <img  alt="" onError={this.callBack} className="avi" src={url} />
  )
}
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Should be `onError={this.callBac}`  not `onError=(this.callBack) ` and callBack should be binded to the component becuase in callBack you refer to this.

Comment: @AndrzejDybionka why `callBac`? And I did not write the whole component to bind the function. Its his mission to do that.

Comment: I "ate" one letter. Should be `onError={this.callBack}`in  buckles not brackets